# error 4046 restoring ipad gen 6

Tags: ipad, restore, error

I'm trying to restore two iPads 6th generation but getting the same error for both and they're both stuck in restore mode (support.apple.com/ipad/restore with the cable and an laptop icon on a black screen).
When I connect the iPad to my MacBook the iPad shows up in Finder but I only get a loading screen there.

Google search only brought up this thread on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/rzvkze/does_anyone_recognize_this_error_code_4046_i_cant/

Any idea how to bring them back to life?

MacBook Info: MacBook Pro (Early 2015), macOS Monterey Version 12.3
Both iPads were on iPadOS 15.5

Comment: Try [Apple Configurator](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1037126344), available in the App Store. It may be able to 'see' the iPads and reset them. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to comment on my problem, it solved my problem. I'd love to mark your answer as correct but can't do it with comments, if you wanna write a comment on the post I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider experimenting with [Apple Configurator](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id1037126344?mt=12) to see if you can reset the iPads through the interface it provides. I've used it for years for my own devices and at work.

Configurator help at this [link](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator).